# PHP Minecraft Votifier

Tags: php, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying me best to get this thing working but I dont know why the minecraft server consoles gives me:
05.04 01:40:29 [Server] INFO /212.1.212.1:58215 lost connection

my code php function:

```
function Votifier($public_key, $server_ip, $server_port, $username)
{
//pharse the public key
$public_key2 = wordwrap($public_key, 65, "\n", true);
$public_key = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$public_key2
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;
//get user IP
$address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//set voting time
$timeStamp = time();

//create basic required string for Votifier
$string = "VOTE\nTest\n$username\n$address\n$timeStamp\n";

//fill blanks to make packet lenght 256
$leftover = (256 - strlen($string)) / 2;
while ($leftover > 0) {
$string.= "\x0";
$leftover--;
}

//encrypt string before send
openssl_public_encrypt($string,$crypted,$public_key);

//try to connect to server
$socket = fsockopen($server_ip, $server_port, $errno, $errstr, 3);
if ($socket)
{
var_dump(fwrite($socket, $crypted)); //on success send encrypted packet to server
}
else
return false; //on fail return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). There is an example on how to use private/public keys here: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#rsakey. You can then use interactive shell like this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
?>
```